# ¿Hay algo así como un antónimo para la raíz latina "auto"?

Tags: etimología, solicitud-de-término, latín, prefijos, antónimos

Hay raíces latinas donde no es muy difícil encontrar su contrario, por ejemplo:

- ***Endo vs Exo***
- ***Infra vs Super***
- ***Pro vs Anti***

Me pregunto si hay algún antónimo para ***auto***, cuyo significado tiene relación con la idea del "sí mismo"; algo, por lo tanto, que refiera a una idea relacionada con "otra cosa".

Comment: En algunas aceptationes hetero- seria posible.

Comment: Si estás preguntando específicamente por el latín, lo mismo sería mejor publicar en [latin.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una posibilidad, dado que *auto-* viene del griego *αὐτός* ("sí mismo") y que *hetero-* más canónicamente es antónimo de *homo-*:

> #### [alo-](https://dle.rae.es/alo-)
>
> Del gr. ἀλλο- *allo-* 'otro, diferente'.
>
> 1. elem. compos. Indica variación o variante. *Alotropía.*

Comment: ¿"variante o variación" antónimo de "sí mismo"?

Comment: @DGaleano hay ejemplos de su uso como *otro*: ej. [autotrasplante](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotrasplante) / [alotrasplante](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alotrasplante)

Comment: Excelente. Esos ejemplos son los que hacían falta. Gracias. +1